# How do I get a promise from a compile in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There's an event that needs to be triggered after a compilation is finished.

This is what my parent controller looks like:

```
myApp.directive("ParentDirective", ["$rootScope", "$compile",
    function($rootScope, $compile) {
        return {
            link: function (scope, element) {
                var onClick = function () {
                    if (!scope.childDir) {
                        scope.childDir = $compile('<div ng-controller="childCtrl"/>')(scope);
                        $(scope.element).append(scope.childDir);
                    }
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('event');
                }

                $(element).click(onClick);
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

And in childCtrl I have an listener:

```
$rootScope.$on('event', doSomething);
```

The problem is that the directive processing takes place after my controller triggers the event. Is there a way to get a promise from the compiler or any way to trigger the event after the compilation takes place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger the event in the [postLink](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) function. Try it.

```
compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
  return {
    pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... },
    post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { 
        $rootScope.$broadcast('event'); 
    }
  }
```